# Translating SQL with join and window function to DAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax, cube, dimensional-modeling

I have a working SQL query, but it needs to be translated to DAX and I'm struggling.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

I have agreements running from a `startdate` to an `enddate` in a fact table. An agreement running for a whole year counts as `1`, meaning `DATEDIFF(startdate, enddate) / 365.0` gives the "weight" of the agreement. It is needed to look at any given month and get the sum of the trailing year's total agreement weights. I also have a dimension table related to the fact table with all dates (single days and in which year/month they belong), which gives me the possibility to perform the following SQL query to get exactly what I want:

```
SELECT
   sub.yearMonth
   ,SUM(sub.[cnt]) OVER (ORDER BY sub.[yearMonth] DESC ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / 365.0 AS [runningYear]
FROM
   (SELECT 
       d.yearMonth
       ,COUNT(*) AS [cnt] 
    FROM Agreememts AS a
    INNER JOIN Date AS d
       ON d.date >= a.startddate AND d.date <= a.enddate
    GROUP BY d.yearMonth
) AS sub
```

I tried to replicate this in a DAX measure ending up with the following:

```
AgreementWeights:=
CALCULATE (
   CALCULATE (
      COUNTROWS ( 'Agreements' );
      FILTER (
        'Agreements';
        'Agreements'[startdate] <= MAX ( 'Date'[date] )
            && 'Agreements'[enddate] >= EDATE ( MAX( 'Date'[date] ); -12)
      )
   );
   CROSSFILTER ( 'Agreements'[receiveddate]; 'Date'[sys_date_key]; NONE )
)
```

The last line is to cut the relationship from the `recieveddate` to the date dimension, which is irrelevant here. This DAX query yields too many rows, but gives the correct result when divided like `(result/365)*100` and I simply cannot figure out why.

An example of the fact table `Agreements`:

```
  ID   startdate   enddate     recieveddate
  0    10-04-2014  12-06-2015  10-03-2014
  1    11-06-2014  11-07-2014  11-05-2014
```

An example of the dimension table `Date`:

```
  ID   date        yearMonth   sys_date_key
  0    10-04-2014  April2014   10042014
  1    11-04-2014  April2014   11042014
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean it yields too many rows? A measure only returns a single value.

Comment: I’m using COUNTROWS - the result of this is too high..